# How ask and answer at boost gmane maillist group?

Tags: email, boost

I want ask and answer questions on

news://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user

What I should do for that? From begin phase (what program, settings, sign up, authorization, posting, subscribing) step by step, please.

Answer (score 0):

1. Register [here](http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost-users) your e-mail that you'd like to post from.
2. E-mail from the above address your question to `boost-users@lists.boost.org`, according to [these policies](http://www.boost.org/community/policy.html). (Note that your first posting(s) might be pre-moderated, so it will take them a bit more time to appear in the mailing list.)

Comment: How I can answer (reply) to other question?

Comment: Because other people can answer question and his message stand as tree leaf at topic.

Comment: @user2704976 If this is a new message, i.e. you got it to your mail-box - just reply to it (avoid top-posting and overquoting). Or you can reply to any message directly on gmane (http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user) -- select the desired message, then select "Followup" from "Action" drop-down menu in the right-upper corner.